# Zsh using 100% of CPU during iWork install

Tags: mac-appstore, defaults

I've been trying to install Keynote and Numbers, but they hang like so:

[image: app store hang screen]

This is associated with a shell script consuming 100% of a CPU:

[image: activity monitor]

That process is `defaults delete com.apple.helpd com.apple.helpd.sdmMapsCreated`, which looks like an operation that shouldn't be long-running at all:

[image]

Killing its grandparent process results in the "an error has occured" message in the app store. What gives? I don't even know how to begin debugging this.

Comment: Please look at the relevant error messages within `/var/log/system.log` at the time of this `zsh -c ...` and include them within your OQ. There might be some sort of lock on the `defaults` command.

Comment: Same problem.  Didn't find anything interesting in the logs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was able to solve this, but I still don't know what caused it.

Iteratively:

1. Watch for a hung `sh` job.
2. Run the command in a terminal.
3. Kill the parent of the hung job with `kill -9`.
4. Return to 1 until no more hung jobs appear.

Comment: Not fun, but worked for me.

Comment: `ps uaxwww | grep zsh` to show the full process command line. For step 2, run what is **after** `zsh -c`.

Answer (score 1):

I just change my shell using `chsh -s /bin/bash $USER`, apply the updates and finally change my shell back to ZSH.